# передача GET параметров

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно реализовать сохранение GET параметров при переходе с одного сайта на другой? К примеру пользователь пришел по ссылке:
http://test.ru/?param1=val1&param2=val2&param2=val3, с него он переходит на основной сайт с сохранением GET параметров
http://general.ru/?param1=val1&param2=val2&param2=val3

Answer (score 1):

Добавить их к ссылке на "основной сайт"?

`$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`
в более сложных случаях - `http_build_query()`